# Swag init generates nothing but "general API information"

Tags: rest, go, swagger, go-gin

**Issue Description**
Swaggo fails to recursively parse Swagger comments in Go files when using the `swag init` command with multiple directories and the `--parseDependency` and `--parseInternal` flags. Only the comments in the main file specified with the `-g` flag are parsed, while the comments in other files within the specified directories are not considered.

Files that contain swaggo comments are internal/transport/http/v1/auth.go, internal/transport/http/v1/trip.go, and cmd/app/main.go

Repo structure is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TJyW.png)

**commands I have run:**
`swag init -d cmd[enter image description here][1]/app/ -g main.go --parseDependency --parseInternal`

`swag init -d cmd/app/,internal/transport/http/v1 -g main.go --parseDependency --parseInternal`

All the commands above produces the same result

**Results**

```
2023/06/29 17:45:38 Generate swagger docs....
2023/06/29 17:45:38 Generate general API Info, search dir:cmd/app/
2023/06/29 17:45:38 Generate general API Info, search dir:internal/transport/http/v1
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const mProfCycleWrap at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mprof.go:165:7, reflect: call of reflect.Value.Len on zero Value
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const locb at /Users/ikramkamat/go/GoWorkSpace/pkg/mod/github.com/pelletier/go-toml/v2@v2.0.8/internal/characters/utf8.go:183:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b10000000": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const hicb at /Users/ikramkamat/go/GoWorkSpace/pkg/mod/github.com/pelletier/go-toml/v2@v2.0.8/internal/characters/utf8.go:184:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b10111111": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const t1 at /usr/local/go/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go:29:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b00000000": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const tx at /usr/local/go/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go:30:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b10000000": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const t2 at /usr/local/go/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go:31:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b11000000": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const t3 at /usr/local/go/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go:32:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b11100000": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const t4 at /usr/local/go/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go:33:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b11110000": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const t5 at /usr/local/go/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go:34:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b11111000": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const maskx at /usr/local/go/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go:36:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b00111111": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const mask2 at /usr/local/go/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go:37:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b00011111": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const mask3 at /usr/local/go/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go:38:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b00001111": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const mask4 at /usr/local/go/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go:39:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b00000111": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const locb at /usr/local/go/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go:46:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b10000000": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const hicb at /usr/local/go/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go:47:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b10111111": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 create docs.go at docs/docs.go
2023/06/29 17:45:40 create swagger.json at docs/swagger.json
2023/06/29 17:45:40 create swagger.yaml at docs/swagger.yaml
```

**generated swagger.yaml**

```
basePath: /api/v1
host: localhost:8000
info:
  contact: {}
  description: REST API for InnoCoTravel App
  license:
    name: Apache 2.0
    url: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
  title: InnoCoTravel API
  version: "1.0"
paths: {}
securityDefinitions:
  ApiKeyAuth:
    in: header
    name: Authorization
    type: apiKey
swagger: "2.0"
```

**Comments in one of the files other than cmd/app/main.g**

```
package v1

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    _ "github.com/itoqsky/InnoCoTravel-backend/docs"
    "github.com/itoqsky/InnoCoTravel-backend/internal/core"
)

//  @Summary        SignUp
//  @Tags           auth
//  @Description    create account
//  @ModuleID       signUp
//  @ID             create-account
//  @Accept         json
//  @Produce        json
//  @Param          input   body        core.User   true    "sign up info"
//  @Success        200     {integer}   integer
//  @Failure        400     {object}    errorResponse
//  @Failure        404     {object}    errorResponse
//  @Failure        500     {object}    errorResponse
//  @Failure        default {object}    errorResponse
//  @Router         /auth/sign-up [post]

func (h *Handler) signUp(c *gin.Context) {
    <other code>
```

**swag version**
e.g. 1.8.12

**go version**
e.g. 1.20.2

**OS**
OSX

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Just include the text in your question, formatted as a code sample when appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Have the same issue too when using **v1.8.16**. Everything works fine after downgrading to **v1.8.4**. You should try downgrade and it work in swaggo

For downgrading to **v1.8.4** use the following command

```
go install github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag@v1.8.4
```

Comment: How can I downgrade it? Actually, what even am I supposed to downgrade?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).